# Restrict Contact list on task based on Account

Tags: tasks, lookup-filter

I am having users create a task on an Account but I only want to allow the user to select Contacts that are associated to the Account that the task is being created on.  I tried to use a filter but it's not working.
For example I tried
Activity: Related To ID = Contact: Account: Contact
I am not using a VF page.
Thanks for Time
M

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if we can have a validation rule as who.accountId is not available. Unless some one here can find a solution through validation rule, I feel it is best to have before insert trigger on task to check. something like

```
trigger abctrigger on Task (before insert) {
    List<Task> tList = trigger.new;
    List<Id> idList = new List<Id>();
    for(Task t : tList) {
        if(t.whoId != null) idList.add(t.whoId);
    }
    Map<Id, Contact> cMap = new Map<Id, Contact>([select id, accountId from contact where Id in: idList]);

    List<Task> tList_failed = new List<Task>();
    for(Task t : tList) {
        if(t.whoId != null && t.whatId != null && t.whatId != cMap.get(t.whoId).accountId) tList_failed.add(t);
    }

    if(tList_failed.size() > 0) tList[0].addError('Please check');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  The code works well not allowing the user to save the task  if the Contact they added to the task is not associated to the Account.  Is there a way to filter the actual Contact list that the user can choose from?  Thanks again for your time. M

Comment: You might need to look at related lookup filter for that..

Comment: pmvsdt,  That's what I had to do.  Create a lookup  and then created a filter using the following criteria.  Activity: Related To ID = field Contact: Account ID.  Thanks,